# Get stuck on JSON data from Wordpress site in Swift 3.0

Tags: json, swift

I'm new to Swift. I am stuck parsing JSON data in my Swift app.
I tried to print out the "title" but it appears nil. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Here is my JSON format:

```
{  
   "status":"ok",
   "count":2,
   "pages":1,
   "category":{  },
   "posts":[  
      {  
         "id":435,
         "type":"post",
         "slug":"tips-the-thao-ngay-10102017",
         "url":"http:\/\/hongbien.online\/tips-the-thao-ngay-10102017\/",
         "status":"publish",
         "title":"Tips th\u1ec3 thao ng\u00e0y 10\/10\/2017",
         "title_plain":"Tips th\u1ec3 thao ng\u00e0y 10\/10\/2017",
         "content":"<p>Ph\u00e1p &#8211; Belarus<\/p>\n<p>\u0110\u01b0\u1ee3c thi \u0111\u1ea5u tr\u00ean s\u00e2n nh\u00e0 v\u00e0 \u0111\u00e1nh gi\u00e1 v\u01b0\u1ee3t tr\u1ed9i so v\u1edbi \u0111\u1ea5u th\u1ee7 nh\u01b0ng v\u1edbi m\u1ee9c k\u00e8o ch\u1ea5p +3 cho Belarus th\u00ec s\u1ebd r\u1ea5t kh\u00f3 kh\u0103n \u0111\u1ec3 c\u00e1c c\u1ea7u th\u1ee7 Ph\u00e1p chi\u1ec1u l\u00f2ng cho c\u00e1c nh\u00e0 \u0111\u1ea7u t\u01b0 trong b\u1ed1i c\u1ea3nh ch\u1ec9 c\u1ea7n gi\u00e0nh chi\u1ebfn th\u1eafng t\u1ed1i thi\u1ec3u l\u00e0 c\u00f3 th\u1ec3 \u0111i ti\u1ebfp.<\/p>\n<p> <a href=\"http:\/\/hongbien.online\/tips-the-thao-ngay-10102017\/#more-435\" class=\"more-link\">Read more<\/a><\/p>\n",
         "excerpt":"<p>Ph\u00e1p &#8211; Belarus \u0110\u01b0\u1ee3c thi \u0111\u1ea5u tr\u00ean s\u00e2n nh\u00e0 v\u00e0 \u0111\u00e1nh gi\u00e1 v\u01b0\u1ee3t tr\u1ed9i so v\u1edbi \u0111\u1ea5u th\u1ee7 nh\u01b0ng v\u1edbi m\u1ee9c k\u00e8o ch\u1ea5p +3 cho Belarus th\u00ec s\u1ebd r\u1ea5t kh\u00f3 kh\u0103n \u0111\u1ec3 c\u00e1c c\u1ea7u th\u1ee7 Ph\u00e1p chi\u1ec1u l\u00f2ng cho c\u00e1c nh\u00e0 \u0111\u1ea7u t\u01b0 trong b\u1ed1i c\u1ea3nh ch\u1ec9 c\u1ea7n gi\u00e0nh chi\u1ebfn th\u1eafng t\u1ed1i thi\u1ec3u l\u00e0 c\u00f3 [&hellip;]<\/p>\n",
         "date":"2017-10-11 22:38:20",
         "modified":"2017-10-11 22:38:20",
         "categories":[  ],
         "tags":[  ],
         "author":{  },
         "comments":[  ],
         "attachments":[  ],
         "comment_count":0,
         "comment_status":"open",
         "custom_fields":{  }
      },
      {  }
   ]
}
```

Here is my Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://hongbien.online/category/tips-the-thao/?json=1")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data : Data?, urlResponse : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                let title = json["posts"]?["title"]
                print(title)
            }
            catch {
                print("Catch the error : \(error)")
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change this one line. You just forgot to put index for
>   array(json["posts"] is array)

```
let title = json["posts"]?[0]["title"]
print(title)
```

Comment: You need to do more than just add the array access. There will be errors about indexing type `Any?`.